# Redirection to 503.shtml URL while there isn't such file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-503

We have a website where we develop all the pages with manual HTML code, except for the `/blog` directory, which is managed in WordPress. A few weeks back, we encountered `example.com/blog` getting redirected to the `/503.shtml` URL, while we didn't have such a file. There is no redirection in the `.htaccess` like that as well. Even the `/503.shtml` showed the contents of our custom `404` page, as I believe the `503` page didn't exist.

Now, I'm aware of the `503` error code being a temporary server-side issue, which resolved itself shortly after. But, I'm wondering what caused the browser to redirect the `/blog` URL `/503.shtml` URL, instead of throwing `503 error` on the page itself.

Is this redirection a normal behavior caused by the browser itself?

Comment: No, the browser did not cause this. Something on the server side did. (F.e. setting up `ErrorDocument` in Apache with absolute URLs, will cause a redirect.)

Comment: You can easily check that it is the server that sends the redirection by a short look into your browser's network console. You will see the request and the redirection as the server's reponse.